# How to enable facebook authentication in Core .NET 2.2 project?

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-core, facebook-authentication, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a project written using `C#` on the top of Asp.NET Core 2.2.

I am using the built-in Identity to enable accounts authentication.

I am now trying to add integration to enable Facebook authentication. I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to create an app on Facebook and then enable it on my site. However, every time I try to log in using Facebook, I get the following error

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

In my Facebook account, in the `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` section I put `https://example.com/signin-facebook` as you can see in the screenshot below.

What else needed to be done in order to successfully enable Facebook authentication in my website?

Here is how I add the providers

```
AuthenticationBuilder authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(); 
foreach (var provider in providerService.GetAll())
{
    if (provider.Name == ExternalLoginProvider.Facebook)
    {
        authBuilder.AddFacebook(options =>
        {
            options.AppId = provider.AppId;
            options.AppSecret = provider.Secret;
        });
    }

    if (provider.Name == ExternalLoginProvider.Twitter)
    {
        authBuilder.AddTwitter(options =>
        {
            options.ConsumerKey = provider.AppId;
            options.ConsumerSecret = provider.Secret;
        });
    }
    // other providers
}
```

Here is a snapshot of my current settings where I added my sie
[image]

Comment: `URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings`-Check your OAuth settings again please

Comment: @TanvirArjel I thought I did. Please check my updated question which has a picture of the settings.

Answer (score 0):

While you whitelisted `https://www.realestatebyareen.com/signin-facebook`, are you testing the Facebook login after deploying the app to this URL or locally?

If locally, then you will also need to whitelist the URL where your local application is hosted, most likely something like `https://localhost:<some-port>/signin-facebook`.